# AWS RDS innoDB with Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, innodb, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

(I'm poor at English. Sorry)

I am using AWS RDS and Lambda.

When I INSERT/UPDATE innoDB row with client tool (sequel pro / toad)
It's not reflected in query result with AWS Lambda. but row data is updated in query(select) with client tool.

It's just updated after past few hours. or after reboot RDS.
MyISAM tables don't occur this problem. Only InnoDB does.

on the contrary to this, INSERT/UPDATE row datas with Lambda has no problem. It query well with client tool too.

How can I fix it?

Environment & Problem:

- always login with same ID (client tools and Lambda)
- autocommit is ON
- Lambda function is Pyhton with pymysql. [It's AWS Example.](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/vpc-rds-deployment-pkg.html)
- UPDATE with Client tool → Lambda SELECT → Didn't Update (Updated in Client tool) → past few hours or Reboot RDS → Updated !
- UPDATE with Lambda → Client tool SELECT → Updated !

I tried these (in client tool):

- query : SHOW PROCESSLIST and Kill ID → Fail
- query : INSERT and COMMIT → Fail

Comment: Want to understand? You're trying to configure a Lambda Function on Amazon RDS table? or You're trying to access RDS table inside a Lambda Function?

Comment: I'm trying to access RDS table inside a Lambda Function. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: This would be exactly the expected behavior if your client tool is holding an open transaction or has autocommit disabled.  When rows are updated inside a transaction, depending on isolation level, other connections cannot see the changes *by design*.  That's how it's supposed to work.  The transaction making the changes must commit them.

Comment: Agreed with @Michael-sqlbot

Comment: Thank you @Michael-sqlbot . I solved it anyway. in Lambda Function, I figure out SELECT query also needs Commit. Basically I'm poor at InnoDB yet.

Comment: If a `BEGIN` is executed, `autocommit` is ignored and a transaction is started.  It is as if the client tool is doing that.